# Create Abstraction layer for Elastic Search NEST client. What should be the return type?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an abstraction layer over the NEST Elastic search client as I do not want business logic to be dependent upon the client so I can change the client if I have to. But what should be the response type? I am not able to use Generic type as it gives me an error:

```
public class StorageClient : IStorageClient
    {
        private readonly IElasticSearchClient _elasticSearchClient;
        public StorageClient(IElasticSearchClient elasticSearchClient)
        {
            _elasticSearchClient = elasticSearchClient;
        }
        public async Task<T> AddData<T>(T requestObject, string index) where T : class
        {
            var response = await _elasticSearchClient.addIndex(requestObject, index);

            return response; I get an error here that cannot convert the NEST index response to type T
        }
    }
```

Here is the Elastic Search Client

```
 public async Task<IndexResponse> addIndex<T>(T document, string index) where T : class
        {

            _client = CreateElasticClient();

            return await _client.IndexAsync(elasticValues, idx => idx.Index(index.ToLower()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of

```
public async Task<T> AddData<T>(T requestObject, string index) where T : class
```

would need to return a requestObject type, but is returning a task of NEST `IndexResponse` type.

I would question the value of having both a abstraction around NEST in the form of `IElasticSearchClient`, and an abstraction around storage in the form of `IStorageClient`. It *seems* like a concrete implementation of `IStorageClient` that uses the NEST client directly would be sufficient.